# Sitewide redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm working on doing a site-wide redirect, while still maintaining a consistent url pattern.

http://www.site1.com/folder/page

**should first redirect to**
http://www.site1.com/redirectHandler?dest=folder/page

**which would ultimately have a link** to http://www.site2.com/folder/page

I can obviously code the last part, but since there are several hundred pages, I'm hoping someone can show how to do the first redirect via htaccess, instead of individual code on each page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some investigation, here's what I found which does the trick (much simpler than I thought)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site1.com/redirectHandler?dest=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Why would you want to redirect twice? That seems unnecessary.

Comment: The client wants to give feedback to the user that the domain switched, over time - it will be a flat 1-way 301 redirect thought